# Fixing of Property Sheet UI problem causes projects from earlier solutions to be cleaned on Azure DevOps - how to fix?

Tags: c++, azure-devops, msbuild

Our company uses two property sheets, one main sheet at the top level of the source, then there is a subfolder representing a sub-category of the product for which there is another property sheet, and all projects under this subfolder reference this property sheet, and the projects reference the macros declared in the first property sheet to find various include folders.  Lets call them SheetA.props and SheetB.props

The first property sheet SheetA.props looks pretty much like any property sheet, in that it influences the projects that are building and provides them with locations of other projects source folders on which they depend via macros, and then sheet SheetB.props builds upon the macros in SheetA.props for the projects under the aforementioned subfolder.

SheetB.props is the problem.  I noticed that the macros don't show up in the Visual Studio UI, but the projects within the solution are able to use these macros defined in the .props file and resolve them to find the correct include folders, when the solution builds.

When I examined SheetB.Props I saw that the section at the bottom which defines the Macros that should show up in the UI was missing. It only has the macro contents section at the top.

So I noted the contents in Notepad, deleted SheetB.Props and then recreated it manually in the Visual Studio UI.  Now all the Macros can be edited, and the two extra macros I needed for my Unit Test Project.

Everything now builds fine within Visual Studio as before, however the CI build on AzureDevops fails.

Our product is built from 7 solutions, each builds on the previous one (in other words for a solution to build, the solution before it has to also be successfully built).  When it gets to Solution 7 we get both linker errors on attempting to open some of the .lib files, and C# errors from types that it doesn't recognise due to missing projects that define types that the C# project uses.

If I revert the updates to SheetB.Props then all builds as normal.

Examining the logs I find many ##[debug] entries listing projects that it is cleaning, when it works this list is exclusively formed from projects belonging to the solution being built.

However in the failing builds I find: `2024-01-04T10:26:08.6177593Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=guid-5;parentid=guid-4;name=Path\To\Solution2Project\SomeProject.vcxproj (Clean);type=Build;starttime=2024-01-04T10:26:08.6120936Z;state=InProgress;targetname=Clean;]`

Now I know why Solution 7 is not completing successfully, it is now cleaning SomeProject.vcxproj which belongs to Solution 2 and so should already have been built, but because its been cleaned the .lib file no longer exists, and the metadata will also be gone which is why one of the C# projects no longer build.

The question I need answered, is why touching SheetB.props causing projects that were successfully built by Solution 2 now being cleaned erroneously by Solution 7?

I did try reverting to the working version of SheetB.props, and just adding the two extra Macros however even without the Macro declaration section, I am still finding it wrongly cleaning up SomeProject.vcxproj.

Comment: It's recommended to share the pipeline definition, show the task where the error reported, to help check why the projects built by Solution 2 are cleaned.